# Random string from vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a question about this code. I got what I was expecting but I don't understand why sometimes I get the result and sometimes not.

In this case, the output suppose to show the word "dive" every time I run the code but sometimes the output is not giving me any value.

Is it because the if statement? How can I get always the result("dive") and not sometimes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    vector <string> Words = {"dive", "friends", "laptop"};

    string n_words = Words[rand() % Words.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        if(n_words.length() <= 4)
        {
            cout << n_words << endl;
        }
    }    
}
```

EDIT ANOTHER EXAMPLE:

I would like to pick up a random word not longer than 4 letters from a list of words with differents lengths. When I run my code sometimes I get "dive" sometimes "lego" and sometimes nothing. Is there any way to get always some of this two values ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    vector <string> Words = {"dive", "table", "laptop", "lego", "friends"}

    string n_words = Words[rand() % Words.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        if(n_words.length() <= 4)
        {
            cout << n_words << endl;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` -- The loop only iterates once, thus you have one chance only to get a hit on the word "dive".  Why did you expect that `dive` will show up every time you run the program?

Comment: You do know what *random* mean? Like sometimes you will get the `"dive"` entry, and sometimes (around two thirds of the time) you will get another element from the vector.

Comment: if I change to: for(int i = 0; i < Words.size(); i++). Sometimes, the output doesn't give me any value like before. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: it's just simple logic, `n_words` may be any string in `"dive", "friends", "laptop"`, as `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` iterates only once, you just need to care about the inner if-statement. And there's only one string with length less than or equal to 4, which is `"dive"`. In other cases there'll be no output.

Comment: If you want the same answer always, you need to seed the same, and not based on time.

Comment: @GasparBonari -- Follow the logic of your code.  What if `n_words` turns out to be "friends"?  You  got the word "friends", not "dive".  Maybe you believed that `rand() % Words.size()` would always equal 0?  What do you believe the purpose of `rand()` is?  Also, wouldn't the program absolutely be useless if randomness *didn't* happen?

Comment: `string n_words = Words[rand() % Words.size()];`  picks a single random string before your loop.

Comment: Use `string n_words = Words[0];` instead of  `string n_words = Words[rand() % Words.size()];` although the whole exercise is odd because you say you don't want randomness.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Now, is there any way to get the same output with a vector of strings ? @SHP

Comment: @GasparBonari I really don't understand what goal you're trying to achieve, to be honest with you.  You have `rand()`, but for some reason, you don't want randomness -- instead you want the output to always be the same.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full and complete assignment or exercise text, copy-pasted as text, including all requirements and limitations. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I edited the post with another example, I hope to be more clear. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @GasparBonari -- Hint -- If I gave you two dice, and asked you to roll a 7, and keep rolling until you get a 7, would you give yourself only one chance?  Or would you keep trying until you get a 7?  Your code gives you one chance to hit that magic word with 4 letters or less.  That's why the `for` loop doesn't make sense (it only loops once).  So think what looping construct allows you to keep trying.

Comment: So you want to randomly select one of the four-letter words, and disregard the rest? Then why don't you copy all the four-letter words to their own vector and select one from that?

Comment: Thanks for explaing, I'll take a look at my foor loop. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: **Do you, perchance, want to just randomly permute (“shuffle”) the word list?** If so, I bet there’s an algorithm for that in the standard C++ library, and you won’t need to manually mess with random numbers. Permutation just changes the order so you won’t get any word twice unless it appeared twice in the word list. If you want random selections to fill the output vector, there may be a function that randomly picks a value from a collection/range – look into `<algorithm>` and `<random>` on cppreference.com :)

Comment: I've done that but it looks more messy in my opinion, I wanted to have all the words togethers in only one vector. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Yes, I haven't found it yet @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica

Comment: Then you need an infinite loop, and inside you randomly select one string from the vector. If the string matches your requirements break out of the loop otherwise let the loop continue. Important caveat: You must make sure that at least *one* element in the vector satisfies your requirements first.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll take a loot at the page right now. @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica

Comment: Amaizing, I got the solution with a while loop. Thanks! @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would copy to a secondary temporary vector, shuffle it, and get the first element of that vector.

And I would have put it in a separate function.

In code something like this perhaps:

```
std::string select_random_short_word(std::vector<std::string> const& long_words)
{
    // Create a vector and copy all "short" words to it
    std::vector<std::string> short_words;
    std::copy_if(begin(long_words), end(long_words), std::back_inserter(short_words),
                 [](std::string const& w) { return w.length() <= 4; });

    // Make sure there are any short words
    if (short_words.size() == 0)
    {
        return "";  // Nope, no short words
    }

    // Randomly shuffle the short words
    std::random_device device;
    std::default_random_engine engine(device());
    std::shuffle(begin(short_words), end(short_words), engine);

    // Return a random short word
    return short_words[0];
}
```

This will reduce your `main` function to simply:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words = {"dive", "table", "laptop", "lego", "friends"};
    std::cout << select_random_short_word(words) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: BTW, the code could be modified to allow for passing the length cutoff for short words as a parameter instead of using a fixed `4`.

Comment: @drescherjm I would then rather allow the user to pass any lambda to define the requirements of the word. Or possibly overloads for length (default `4`) and generic lambda? :)